# Deleting table record, but not duplicates

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

My database contains multiple rows with the same data, which are ok but when I go to delete one it deletes the others. How could I manipulate this code so that only one of the rows is deleted, instead of all the rows that have the name corresponding to nametxt.Text for example?

```
 Dim conn As New OleDbConnection
        conn = New OleDbConnection
        dbprovider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
        Dim databasePath = "Data Source = FULL YUGIOH ACCESS DATABASE.accdb;"
        conn.ConnectionString = dbprovider & databasePath
        Dim Stringc As String = "delete from sampledeck33 where name='" & nametxt.Text & "'"
        Dim command As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(Stringc, conn)


        Try
            conn.Open()
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            command.Dispose()
            conn.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)

        Finally
            conn.Dispose()

        End Try
```

Comment: Whenever you execute an `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statement, every record that matches the specified `WHERE` clause will be affected. If you want to ensure that you only affect one record then your `WHERE` clause must uniquely identify that record. How you do that depends on the specifics of the case. One option might be to use a subquery in the `WHERE` clause that gets the ID of the first record in the same table that matches the other criteria.

Comment: Also, learn how to use parameterised queries. As it stands, you're at risk of having a malicious user delete everything in your database.

Comment: Don't worry jmcilhinney I use parameters for adding values to the database! Thanks for the advice I'll see if I can learn to subquery my delete statement

Answer (score 0):

You are deleting all records with a specific name, instead you must have a unique value in a row like ID or lastname or something that makes that row unique and then check for both id and name or else each row containing that name will be deleted. Also if you don't have a choice and want to delete only one you can use "order by id desc limit 1" and delete only that one..

Comment: I should be able to use ID to delete them I think I'll test it out when saving my data to give it a specific ID